# Php filter_var function

Tags: php

I know that the function filter_var() returns true or false but when I mean if I have

```
if( filter_var( $value , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) )
    echo 'value is sanitized';
else 
    echo 'value is sanitized';
```

Can anyone explain when this function returns true or false?

Comment: The manual clearly says: *Returns the filtered data, or `FALSE` if the filter fails.*

Comment: [filter_var() PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Answer (score 1):

It will never return `true`. It will return `false` if `$value` is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As @deceze says, you either get the sanitized variable back, or FALSE if the function errors out.

Now, PHP lets you do something interesting: if a variable is defined and is used in a conditional statement, anything that could not be implicitly cast to a Boolean value of FALSE (i.e. an empty string or an actual false value) will be considered equivalent to a Boolean value of TRUE. We use this sort of thing all the time when, say, iterating over a dataset retrieved from a database.

So, if you call `filter_var` and successfully get a value back for `$value`, the `if()` statement surrounding the call to `filter_var` uses the value of `$value` as it's conditional.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is **the value of the first argument** if the function succeeds, otherwise it will return **`false`**.

```php
$x = 5;
$y = 3;
$z = 11;
$t = 'abc';
$options = array(
    'options'   =>  ['min_range' => 5, 'max_range' => 10],
    'flags'     =>  FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR
);
if (false === filter_var($x, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)) {
    // filter_var will return the value of $x (5)
    // No exceptions will be thrown
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$x is not a valid input");
}
if (false === filter_var($y, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$y is not a valid input");
}
if (false === filter_var($z, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$z is not a valid input");
}
if (false === filter_var($t, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("$t is not a valid input");
}
```

The only variable that will not throw an exception is `$x` because it's an integer and it's inside the range defined by `$options['options']`.

See also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php